# Read multiple jQuery.val() into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, iteration

I have some code that looks like this that works just fine:

```
var info = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     info[i] = $('#info_' + i).val();
}
```

The problem is that this pattern is very common in my application with some minor variations.
What i would like to do is to make this into a oneliner something like this where info becomes an array:

```
var info = $('[id^="info_"]').each().val();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to Dogbert. All that was missing in his example was the `.get()`

Here is the solution i ended up using:

```
var info = $('[id^="info_"]').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use jQuery.map

```
var info = $('[id^="info_"]').map(function() { return $(this).val(); } )
```

Comment: Just add one .get() and your home. See my full answer for more info.

Comment: Actually, this should be your accepted answer. Anyways... `;)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[id^="info_"]').each(function(){ info.push($(this).val()); });
```

should do

Comment: Don't you have to have one declaration statement and one assignment statement when you do it like this?